# Custom grafana datasource plugin to wrap external REST API

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a data-source plugin which can communicate with an external REST API and provide relevant data to draw a panel.

Anyone with previous experience?

Comment: As per now I went through one existing datasource to understand this. But unable to find any documentation on this.

Comment: Have you finished your data source plugin?

Comment: I had the same issue, and found the JSON plugin too fiddly. So I created a trully REST plugin you might want to have a look at; https://github.com/Pithikos/rest-datasource

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Simple JSON Datasource](https://grafana.net/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource) does roughly what you're proposing, and would definitely be a good base for you to start from.

There is also [documentation on datasource plugins](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/docs/sources/plugins/developing/datasources.md) available.

Comment: I find the [strava-datasource](https://github.com/grafana/strava-datasource) a much better starting point since it show how to make the backend part of a plugin as well (If you want to do auth for example)

Comment: Does it only support STRAVA Official Api? Can we use it to monitor our own APIs?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Grafana Infinity datasource](https://yesoreyeram.github.io/grafana-infinity-datasource) for connecting to REST API endpoints.

This plugin can connect to any REST API and present the data to grafana. You can use CSV,JSON and GraphQL endpoints. Documentation site have more examples on how to connect with external APIs

*Note: I am the author of the plugin. If you see any bugs in the datasource, report it at github site.*

[image]

Comment: can the Inifinity also supports query/params/oauth..? As I wanted to call my BE, with different params .

Comment: This is an awesome plugin, should be included in Grafana official plugins